# How can i upload a file in a directory using ruby mine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rubymine

This is my modal file data_file.rb

```
    class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  def self.save(upload)
    name =  upload['datafile'].original_filename
    directory = "public/data"
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(upload['datafile'].read) }
  end
end
```

This is my controller file

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :file => 'app\views\upload\uploadfile.html.erb'
  end
  def uploadFile
    post = DataFile.save(params[:upload])
    render :text => "File has been uploaded successfully"
  end
end
```

and this is my view file

```
 <h1>File Upload</h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'uploadFile' do  %>
<p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label> :
  <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
<%= end %>
```

Whenever I try to access the view file using syntax `http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload/index`.....i get the following error

Showing C:/Users/pratik/RubymineProjects/upload/app/views/upload/uploadfile.html.erb where line #6 raised:

```
C:/Users/pratik/RubymineProjects/upload/app/views/upload/uploadfile.html.erb:6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
');@output_buffer.append= ( end );@output_buffer.to_s
                               ^
C:/Users/pratik/RubymineProjects/upload/app/views/upload/uploadfile.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
C:/Users/pratik/RubymineProjects/upload/app/views/upload/uploadfile.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
Extracted source (around line #6):

3: <p><label for="upload_file">Select File</label> :
4:   <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
5: <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
6: <%= end %>
```

This project is a sample project on tutorialpoints.com. However when i try to do this it fails. i am using ruby mine as IDE. Can anyone please guide me?? It will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your view file: `<%= end %>`

You need to remove the `=` sign

**Answer to your second question**

`<%= form_tag :action => 'uploadFile' do  %>` is faulty

- Open your console
- `cd` in your application directory: `cd \Users\pratik\RubymineProjects\upload`
- type `rake routes`
- You will see among a lot of lines, something that should resemble to (your output may be different) :

  ```
  upload GET    /upload(.:format)    upload#index
         POST   /upload(.:format)    upload#create
  ```
- on the left side of the "GET", note the name that appear (in my example its 'upload' it may be different in your output)
- then finally use this name in your view `form_tag` by appening `_path` to it, so as a result you should have something like this: `<%= form_tag upload_path do  %>`

Comment: ....I tried your solution. Then the following error occurs-:

Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"uploadFile", :controller=>"upload"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: Don't be in a rush, we are not paid to help you. Plus you could use your idle time to search the solution by your self on google. Anyhow this question is another question, but still I edited my answer to try and help you

Comment: ...Sorry for the rush. But I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have to submit a project by Friday. I have done googling for now 4 days and still i can't find any solution. So I need some urgent help......
I tried your solution but the file is not getting uploaded in the directory.....only the url changes from
http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload/index 
to
http://127.0.0.1:3000/upload/index?action=uploadfile

Comment: So perhaps your route are not correct. Look it is going to be impossible for me to walk with you step by step along each and every error you have. It's obvious that you need more time to learn the basics of Rails, and Friday seems pretty tight deadline. I advise you to check videos from http://railscasts.com/ and start by the last one, you'll learn a lot of techniques there. Sorry I can't do much more. Good luck